# Calculating forward error of a function in c

Tags: c

I'd like to understand how to calculate the forward, and backward error of a function using the C double (64bit) type.

For example, how would I identify the forward error of the following function:

```
double func(double x){
    return (pow(x,2.0)/cos(x));
}
```

If the relative error is known to be = 10^-15.

I know that the forward error is the difference in value between the exact answer f(x), and the computed answer ^f(x).
And the backward error is the difference in value between the value ^x, used to compute ^f(x), and the true value of x that would give the calculated value from ^f(x).

The problem I have is that I have no idea how to calculate these errors in practice.

Thank you.

Comment: Just calculate with long double and compare result to calculate forward error?

Comment: As long as `long double` is of wider precision, this should provide a reasonable answer.  Should you want the _exact_ answer (which may be impossible) or other analysis, check the http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Computing (as opposed to estimating) these errors depends on somehow being able to compute the exact answer.  If you could do that, then you wouldn't be wondering about errors in the first place.

Comment: The point of the exercise is to determine the error with double point precision and therefore (hopefully) show that the error is relatively negligible in general purpose programming.

Thank you for the suggestions, I'll continue trying to estimate error using long doubles as a comparison.

Comment: BTW Nice name "Arc" for a post about `cos()`.

Answer (score 1):

Sample forward difference using extended precision.

Use `volatile` to prevent `double` code from using extended precision calculations.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

long double func_test_forward(volatile double x) {
  #ifdef LDBL_DIG
    assert(LDBL_DIG > DBL_DIG);
  #endif
  volatile double y = func(x);
  long double ly = powl(x, 2.0)/cosl(x);
  return y - ly;
}
```

Comment: How closely should these forward error functions match for say `func(x) { return (pow (x, 2.0) - x)/(2 * x + 1); }` with `0 < x < 100` ?

Comment: @David C. Rankin A max forward error (using OP's def) is about 9e-15 for your `func()`.  For OP's `func()` it is far worse as `1/cosl(x);` may approach infinity.

Comment: Use values below, near and above `odd_integer*M_PI/2` to see larger errors.

Answer (score 0):

`func()` is a problematic function.  Ignore the `pow(x,2.0)` part as that is well behaved.  The rest of the function is `1/cos(x)` or [`secant(x)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Reciprocal_functions)  with poles every odd multiple of π/2.

[image]

Assuming a *good* `cos(x)`, that function will never return 0.0.  (Mathematically, only `cosine(odd*π/2)` returns 0.0 and no `double` is *exactly* an odd multiple of `π/2` - all finite `double` are rational, π is not.)  But `1/cos(x)` will have extreme values for values near `odd*π/2`, but even so, `cos()` will have small relative error.  In theory: +/-1 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place).

Along with the `pow()` and the division - each contributing 0.5 ULP, a good math library with an non-overflowed result: total no more than 2 ULP error.  Overflow can obviously occur with values of `x > sqrt(DBL_MAX)`.

Now assuming a *not so good* `cos(x)`, slect values near `odd*π/2` may simply return `0.0` and a secant of  `INF`, so the forward error is infinity.

[Argument reduction for huge arguments: Good to the last bit](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~phatak/645/supl/Ng-ArgReduction.pdf) gets into how good trig functions are calcaulated